# SAP HANA: How to get distinct characters from a column data value containing ',' and decrement the count

Tags: hana

Example:

doc_details table
OUTPUT:

```
department_id         department_name           count_offices           office_names
101,201,204,401         b,b,c,b                       4                HQ,TCM,TCM,SCM
```

The above example is the information of doctor A1. The table contains the information of which all departments the doctor is working in which all branches with the department_id.

Doctor A1 is working in department b in all the 3 offices(HQ,TCM,SCM) with an exception of office TCM where he works in 2 departments(b,c). This is why the office count in count_offices column is having count as 4. Each of the offices are having department where the department name is same but the department_id assigned to each department based on branch is distinct.

How to write the sql query to get the following output

```
 department_id         department_name           count_offices          office_names
 101,201,204,401           b,c                         3                 HQ,TCM,SCM
```

The department_id column should contain all the distinct department_id of all the departments the doctor is assigned with the above output. The count_offices column value has to be decremneted based on the distinct names in office_names column

Comment: What did you search? What did you try? It's not clear where you get data concerning "department b in all the 3 offices(HQ,TCM,SCM) with an exception of office TCM where he works in 2 departments(b,c)". Please focus on one question at a time, I feel that you ask 2 same questions concerning departments and offices (or almost). In fact you're looking for a SQL function to split text at a given character, and then to join a table of values into one text. I guess it's a very frequent question and there are lots of answers in the Web.

Comment: ok..how to split the text at a given character

Comment: there is no output because there is no input in your question, just wishful data of what you wish to see as a result. Put your query and your input dataset